# Updated to Python 3.7 from 3.6, but import errors whenever I try to import previously installed packages for Python3 (such as networkx)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just recently updated to Python3.7 from 3.6. However, many of my packages such as numpy and networkx that I have been using are suddenly not available when I try to do `import` in python3. I reckon that this may be a problem with my paths but I have no idea how to fix it, and I'm afraid of messing up my Python more than I already have. I understand that I can simply install whatever I need with `pip3`but there should be a better way to transfer my old packages over to this new version of Python, right? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Using pip is the correct and best way to do that. You might mess up more when blindly copying packages between different Python versions forth and back.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do following

1. first create a virtual environment having python 3.7 as base.
2. from python 3.6 do run command : `pip freeze > requirement.txt`
3. activate python 3.7 then in that virtual env run command , python -m pip install -r requirement.txt`

all done.

Comment: Also you can upgrade all packages with this one liner:     `pip freeze — local | grep -v ‘^\-e’ | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U`

Comment: require linux machine for this